# split Name from CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell-3.0

I'm working on a script to create shared mailboxes and security groups, then add users to the security groups, but the user names are formatted as "firstname lastname" (john doe) and the script can't find the users, only when I switch the name to "doe, john" it works.

I did find some articles to switch from "last, first" to "first, last", but when I try to change it doesn't work.

This is what I have so far, and it's not working:

```bsh
Import-Csv "c:\import.csv" | foreach { 
    $_.user = "{1) {0}" -f ($_.user -split '(0), (1)' )
    $_ 
} | Export-Csv "c:\export.csv"
```

Comment: Your code says the names in the CSV have the form "doe, john", but your text says they have the form "john doe". Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split at spaces (or commas followed by spaces, depending on what your actual data look like). Don't include grouped submatches of the values in the split expression. You only include grouped submatches when using the `-replace` operator, which is what I would prefer:

```bsh
Import-Csv 'c:\import.csv' | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.user = $_.user -replace '^(.*) (.*)$', '$2, $1'
    $_ 
} | Export-Csv 'c:\export.csv' -NoType
```

As an alternative to `ForEach-Object` you could use `Select-Object` with a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```bsh
Import-Csv 'c:\import.csv' |
    Select-Object -Property *,@{n='user';e={$_.user -replace '^(.*) (.*)$', '$2, $1'}} -Exclude user |
    Export-Csv 'c:\export.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: this work well if the name have comma but my CSV file doesnt have comma example john Doe want to be Doe, John

Comment: **this is the final code. thanks Ansgar Wiechers *** 'Import-Csv 'c:\import.csv' |
    Select-Object -Property *,@{n='user';e={$_.user -replace '^(.*) (.*)$', '$2, $1'}} -Exclude user |
    Export-Csv 'c:\export.csv' -NoType'

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks Ansgar but my CVS file doesn't contain comma so I tweaked your code and final version below, thanks again**

```
Import-Csv 'c:\import.csv' |
Select-Object -Property *,@{n='user';e={$_.user -replace '^(.*) (.*)$', '$2, $1'}} -Exclude user | 
Export-Csv 'c:\export.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: That's why I had asked for clarification.